# Como receber a localização real de um ficheiro

Tags: java, html, jsp, file-upload

Eu faço o upload de ficheiros para uma pasta, que funciona ao correr no eclipse. Mas quando tento fazer upload através de algum browser, não me é permitido devido à segurança do mesmo.

A minha questão é, existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o browser retorne a localização do ficheiro? Ou se existe alguma forma de enviar o file para poder copiá-lo para a pasta destino?

Caso se necessário para elaborar uma resposta deixo em baixo o meu código.

```
//caminho relativo da pasta destino
final String Dest = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/";

public void addMusica(String musica_nome, Part musica, String ano) throws IOException {

    String fileName = getFileName(musica);

    File data = null;

    try {

        File music = new File(fileName);

        data = new File(Dest + music.getName());

        Files.copy(music.toPath(), data.toPath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//tratamento do path
private String getFileName(Part part) {

    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");

    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não. Isso é uma *feature* do navegador justamente para proteger o usuário de ter a estrutura de disco acessada. Eu, por exemplo, não quero que nenhum site saiba das minhas fotos familiares guardadas no C:\notporn\reallynotporn\juju.png. Se precisa de acesso ao disco do usuário, talvez devesse repensar sobre o design da sua aplicação, *maybe* web não seja o caminho.

Comment: Você quer que um site acesse/controle a máquina do usuário?

Comment: @Renan as vezes eu vejo um texto teu e fico a me perguntar se fui eu que o escrevi õ_ó quem será clone de quem?

Comment: Se eu digito @Renan eu indexo quem?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não apenas quero fazer upload de ficheiros, eu nunca tinha feito mas tenho um projecto em mente que pode ser alguma coisa para mim

Comment: @Everson eu recebi a notificação.

Comment: Mas se quer o upload então qual a necessidade de obter a localização?

Comment: `Ou se existe alguma forma de enviar o file para poder copiá-lo para a pasta destino` Um controlo `<input type="file">` faz exatamente isso.

Comment: Esta usando `Servlet`?

Comment: @Renan se for isso, então o problema é no back-end, o JSP não trata o upload "sozinho" tem que escrever o `doPOST`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim eu estou a usar Servlet.